# Xcode does not run test targets in the order specified in Target Dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode

My iOS project has three targets, the main app target X, and two test targets T1 and T2. I have specified the following target dependencies in Build Phases: T1 depends on X, and T2 depends on X and T1. When I run the tests however, T2 always runs before T1, resulting in test failures. In the test navigator, T2 does appear before T1, but shouldn't the tests be run in the order specified in target dependencies, instead of the order they are listed in the navigator? Apart from target dependencies, are there other settings necessary that I might have missed?

Also, I have tried turning off "Parallelize Build" in Edit Schemes, it didn't make any differences.

I am using Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Are you talking about the order that test bundles *build* in, or the order in which Xcode *runs tests* during a Test action? Target Dependencies affect only the former. The latter is a scheme setting.

Comment: Hi @rickster, how do I configure the order in which Xcode runs the test targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target Dependencies specified in Build Phases determine the order in which Xcode *builds* targets.

To change the order in which Xcode *runs* test bundles in a Test action, you'll need to change scheme settings. Choose Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... and select the Test action:

[image: test action editor]

In there you'll find a list of the test bundles built by your separate test targets ("Mac_Calc_Tests" and "SampleCalcTests" in the screenshot). To change the order tests run in, drag the bundles up and down to reorder the list.